# Cannot Find Package Manager on Weka GUI

Tags: weka

I have installed Weka 3.6.10 on Windows 7.  When I start up the GUI version and go to Tools, the options are: ArffViewer, SQLViewer and Bayes net Editor.  There is no package manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package Manager introduced in [3.7.2](http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+the+package+manager?). Therefore it is normal that you can not find it in 3.6.X